# Problema al importar go-polyline en Visual studio code

Tags: vscode, go

Me pidieron que utilizara la siguiente clase en de github para un proyecto: https://github.com/twpayne/go-polyline ; hice la importacion,  pero a la hora de seguir me aparecen un error y ese genera el resto:[image: problema en polyline_test.go]

[image: problema con go.mod]

en si, ¿de que manera se puede arreglar ese error? gracias

Answer (score 2):

¿Has instalado el módulo antes de importarlo?

```
$ go get https://github.com/twpayne/go-polyline
```